# Is there a way to use a npm package without d.ts definition on TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

Is there a way to use a npm package without d.ts definition on TypeScript and node js? And if yes, how can i achieve that?

Currently, I have something like this, and it throws an error, that tell me "cannot find module 'node-rest-client'", and is because .d.ts file not exists.

```
import * as NodeRest from 'node-rest-client';

export class MyClass {
}
```

EDIT
I solved like this:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="node-rest-client" />
let NodeClient = require('node-rest-client');
export class MyClass { }
```

It's good this solution, or is better implements Dan's response?

Comment: What's throwing the error? The TypeScript compiler? Anyway, you could define your own definition file for the parts of the module that you're using.

Comment: The error is being throwing by VS Code IDE. I don't want to make a new d.ts file... It's a lot of work and not worth it

Comment: To this I say, welcome to TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

I would reconsider adding the types, at least on it's basic form.

you'll be missing the main reason to use typescript

but, sometimes is not convenient, or you want to stay focus on the current task.

in  that case, when in "Node" or using a bundler ( webpack, ...etc)

you can always resort to "require"

greeter.js

```
module.exports = {
    greet: () => "hello"
}
```

greeter.test.ts

```
import * as assert from "assert";
interface IGreeter {
    greet(): string;
}
const greeter: IGreeter = require("./greeter");
describe("amodule", () => {
    it("works", () => {
        assert.equal(greeter.greet(), "hello");
    });
});
```

or simply (noImplicitAny: false)

```
require("./greeter").greet()
```

or (noImplicitAny: true)

```
(require("greeter") as any).greet()
```